# Does Joomla have an application-wide common shared storage or cache?

Tags: joomla

My server needs to log-in to another server (for accessing payment API). Result of successful log-in operation is a `session token` that is valid for 25 minutes.

Where can I store this `session token` so that it is available across multiple requests *and* multiple users? (i.e. user session is not an acceptable solution).

I need some sort of an application state or cache storage.

Just to demonstrate the problem - a file could be used to store this value, but I don't want to deal with concurrency, and security implications this solution comes with. I would prefer an in-memory solution.

Comment: This article is written for a separate purpose, but it should work in your case: http://docs.joomla.org/Using_caching_to_speed_up_your_code. You would want to wrap the function that logs into the other server in the cache method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either the core JSession or JCache framework objects.

http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getSession

http://docs.joomla.org/Using_caching_to_speed_up_your_code

http://docs.joomla.org/Cache

Comment: What is the scope of JCache storage? is it a request, user session, or  the whole application? The documentation is somewhat vague about it.

Comment: For both, once set, the data will be available application wide.  JSession attaches to the user session object, which by default Joomla manages in the DB.  The JCache object will use the filesystem by default but can be configured to use memcache.  Both allow you to manually choose the index and create groups.  If your use case depends heavily on cache you might consider hand rolling a solution, i've gone both ways; but especially if you're hosting on load balanced environment with centralized caching like AWS elasticache.